# Controlling the locale of my IBM Notes Plug-in Run Configuration

Tags: eclipse-plugin, lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I'm trying my hand at writing a Notes Plug-in and have been following Ulrich Krause's slides from ICONUK2014. I've installed Eclipse 3.4.2, Lotus Expeditor Toolkit 6.2.3 and have a part-success for the 'hello, world' plug-in. It works, but the locale coming up is german, which I don't want.

I've tried to look into the Run Configuration, but couldn't find where to override the locale. Can you help?

```
osgi> 2015/01/11 20:30:08.259 KONFIG eclipse.buildId=20131002-1404
java.fullversion=JRE 1.6.0 IBM J9 2.4 Windows 7 x86-32 jvmwi3260sr14-20130704_155156 (JIT enabled, AOT enabled)
J9VM - 20130704_155156
JIT  - r9_20130517_38390
GC   - GA24_Java6_SR14_20130704_1138_B155156
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=de_CH
Framework arguments:  -product com.ibm.notes.branding.notes -pluginCustomization C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes\framework\rcp\eclipse/../plugin_customization.ini -personality com.ibm.rcp.platform.personality
Command-line arguments:  -product com.ibm.notes.branding.notes -data C:\workspacercp/../runtime-New_configuration -dev file:C:/workspacercp/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/MyFirstPlugin/dev.properties -console -pluginCustomization C:\Program Files (x86)\IBM\Notes\framework\rcp\eclipse/../plugin_customization.ini -personality com.ibm.rcp.platform.personality
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried using the -NL parameter to set the language?

Comment: I did but did it in the wrong section - the jvm parameters. I'm confused as to which jvm is doing what, to be honest.

Answer (score 1):

David got me fiddling around and I found the place to set the -nl parameter. Still confused, though.

[image]